# Combined Semi-transpose of a data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

Consider the following query :

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Data] VARCHAR(100),
  [Column1] VARCHAR(100),
  [Column2] VARCHAR(100),
  [Column3] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @T1([Data],[Column1],[Column2],[Column3])
    VALUES
        ('Data1','C11','C21','C31'),
        ('Data2','C12','C22','C32'),
        ('Data3','C13','C23','C33'),
        ('Data4','C14','C24','C34'),
        ('Data5','C15','C25','C35');

SELECT * FROM @T1;
```

The output looks like the following:

[image]

Now we want to keep the Data column and for each other column stack the result of select for that column into the final table. In other words the following query produces the output:

```
-- I am looking for a better solution than below!
DECLARE @output TABLE([Data] VARCHAR(100),[Column] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @output([Data],[Column])
    (SELECT [Data],[Column1] FROM @T1
      UNION
    SELECT [Data],[Column2] FROM @T1
      UNION
    SELECT [Data],[Column3] FROM @T1)

SELECT * FROM @output
```

What would be a better cleaner approach than above to produce the final output? As the number of columns increases it means for every single new column I need to have a separate insert which appears to be a crude solution. Ideally I am looking for a pivot-based solution but I couldn't come up with something concrete.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use `apply` instead of `union` :

```
select t1.data, t2.cols
from @t1 t1 cross apply
     ( values ([column1]), ([column2]), ([column3]) ) t2(cols);
```

Comment: Point donation in Stackoverflow is not available otherwise I would have donated some extra 20 points for your very nice efficient answer. kudos!

Answer (score 2):

Certainly Yogesh's solution would be more performant. However, since your columns  expand over time, here is one approach that will "dynamically" unpivot your data **WITHOUT** actually using Dynamic SQ:

**Example**

```
Select A.[Data]
      ,C.*
 From  @T1 A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(100)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Id','Data','Other-Columns','To-Exclude')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: What sorcery is this? Didn't know SQL Server can be this dynamic

Comment: @MichaelBuen  Thanks for the grin  :)   A word of caution,  NULL values are excluded and XML does not like special characters in column names.   Other than that, it will UNPIVOT virtually any table, view and/or query